# Floating point exception while running sqlplus

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I'm getting 'Floating point exception' when trying to run Oracle InstantClient sqlplus.
Environment information:

```
ORACLE_HOME=/home/half/vendor/instantclient/instantclient_12_1/
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/half/vendor/instantclient/instantclient_12_1/
```

slqplus:

```
/home/half/vendor/instantclient/instantclient_12_1/sqlplus
```

OS:

> Red Hat Enterprise Linux AS release 4 (Nahant Update 5)

Both instantclient and os are 64 bit

Appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably dont need the answer anymore but I had the same problem today. Took a few hours to figure it out.

This may not apply to you but its what happened to me. The sqlplus binaries were compiled on a newer kernel.

```
"uname -a" gave me:  Linux...2.4.21...  (not full output)
```

And:

```
"file /opt/oracle/app/oracle/product/10.1.0.4/bin/sqlplus" gave me: ...for GNU/Linux 2.6.9...
```

Its not really a problem with sqlplus but its something I overlooked for a few hours and hopefully it helps someone else.

Comment: that's strange.. 'uname -r' gave me 2.6.9-55.ELsmp. 'file sqlplus' gave me for GNU/Linux 2.6.9... So I guess the versions do match.

Comment: It appears that the Linux kernel was recently updated, works now.
Thanks!